# C# Stream writeablebitmap among multiple threads

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, streaming, writeablebitmap

I have searched for a while regarding this problem. Got some solution, but none of them is solving my issue. The scenario is, I am fetching and processing a bitmap stream in background thread and after each frame is ready, I am trying to update the bitmap in MainWindow. I am pasting the key code-snippet here to explain the scenario.

UI Thread / MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
object lockObject = ThreadLockProvider.sharedInstance.LockObject;

lock (lockObject)
{
   WriteableBitmap imageFromBackgroundThread = this.webserver.getForegroundBitmap().Clone();
   this.newImage         = new WriteableBitmap(imageFromBackgroundThread );
   this.IconImage.Source = this.newImage;
}
```

Background Thread / ImageProcessor.cs

```
object lockObject = ThreadLockProvider.sharedInstance.LockObject;

lock (lockObject)
{
     // do the image processing tasks with this.foregroundBitmap                        
}
```

When I am executing the code, I am getting the error in the main thread - 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.' Can't figure out why. Can anyone help me in solving the problems? I am already gone through this links-

[Trouble with locking an image between threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596429/trouble-with-locking-an-image-between-threads)

[C# threading bitmap objects / picturebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438673/c-sharp-threading-bitmap-objects-picturebox)

[Writeablebitmap exception when having multiple threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413132/writeablebitmap-exception-when-having-multiple-threads)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `Freeze` before using the bitmap in the UI thread. And you can only access the Image control by means of its Dispatcher:

```
newImage = new WriteableBitmap(imageFromBackgroundThread);
newImage.Freeze();
IconImage.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => IconImage.Source = newImage));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this line

```
this.IconImage.Source = this.newImage;
```

with the below code

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
    new Action(delegate()
    {
        this.IconImage.Source = this.newImage;
    }));
```

Comment: Don't forget to call `newImage.Freeze()` before calling the Dispatcher. @Shuvro: And do not make unnecessary copies of the bitmap, like first `Clone` and then create another new WriteableBitmap.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution removed the runtime error, but does not sets the image in UI.
Thanks @Clemens for your helpful suggestion. I have mistakenly created two copies. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the UI objects like this:

Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { // Update UI ojects here});